# Eclipse Inspect(Ctrl+shift+I) not working

Tags: eclipse

I checked out a maven project in Eclipse and am unable to Inspect a Variable (right click on the variable and click Inspect option).

When I attempt to do so, I get the following message :

```
To perform any evaluation, an expression must be compiled in the 
context of a java project's build path. The current execution 
context is not associated with a java project in the work-space.
```

Can any one know what the reason for this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by did the following:

Right click on the `project ->build path -> select source tab -> add folder` and then i added 
    the folder which contains the java classes.

Answer (score 14):

**[This](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/153106/)** might be useful:

> Find the thread in your debug window that you are in the breakpoint for. Right click on it. Under relaunch should be an edit launch configuration selection. Select that.
>
> Select Source tab. Add. Java Project. Select the java project that the code exists in.

Comment: so in order to printStackTrace on an exception, I need the source-code of that exception? Seems a lame limitation of Eclipse to me...

Answer (score 4):

Also, in your launch configuration, be sure that the source path is correctly specified.

That is to say:
Run/Debug Configurations / Source tab / Add... / Java Project

Make sure the project containing your source code is in that list!

Comment: That is it in my case, but with server. Double click on server -> open launch configuration -> source -> add -> "your project". (Source folder should be selected as mentioned by PSR.)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the run configuration was configured correctly. But I needed to:

- right click on the thread
- click: Edit Source Lookup...
- check: Search for duplicate source files on the path

Comment: You can also configure it via run configuration. The search for duplicate source files is important. It will open a dialog for every class, which "source" to select. Make sure to select the ".class" file instead of the ".java" one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message.

To solve that
`"Debug Configuration" >> {{JAVA_DEBUG_APPLICATION_NAME}} >> Source (tab)`

Check the source is added correctly,

For me,

1. while debugging the java code it opens the class file, which should not be edited.
2. got the error message too,

I have removed the sources from the source tab, It solved both the problem